# How to make ng-repeat filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Struggling to implement the filter like here [ngrepeatFilter](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

my data structure is like that:

```
$scope.books = [
                {
                    id: 'id1',
                    contents: {
                        name: '<span>1Alain du sceau france</span><br><span> Canada Madagascar philipine</span>',
                        price: 'price1',
                        date: '111'
                    }
                },
                {
                    id: 'id2',
                    contents: {
                        name: '<span>2Name zu Long zu Schreiben Bis Here ist Ein Beispiel</span><br><span>Maneschester Canada Madagascar philipine</span>',
                        price: 'price2',
                        date: '2'
                    }
                },
                .........etc

            ];
```

But it seems working only for book.contents['date'] field in my use case rather than to work with the book.contents['name'] : My first goal is to be able to filter by name and if I could be able to filter by both name and date or by all three field name date price it would be much better.

[MyCodePen](https://codepen.io/adier/pen/bOXYbV)

In the following

```
 <li class="animate-repeat fc-event" ng-repeat="book in books| orderBy: book.contents['date'] | filter:q as results track by book.contents['name']"  
             id="{{book.id}}">
```

I am facing a lot of problems to successfully implement it:

```
N.B: 
   1) class="animate-repeat" not included with fc-event
      means No : .animate-repeat.fc-event 
      included in CSS File.
   2) orderBy book.contents['date'] is not working: 111 
      is the first one it should be the last one.
      book.contents['date'] uses $sce.trustAsHtml 
      see 173,174,175 lines in js file.
      also it uses ng-bind-html="book.contents['name']"
      see line 38 from html file

    3) when filtering by input text : 
       1 it works
       1Alain it doesn't work  which results 
       No results found...
       2Name it doesn't work No results found...


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.7"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-vs-repeat/blob/master/dist/angular-vs-repeat.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div id='external-events'>
  <h4 >Draggable books</h4>
  <br><br>I have {{books.length}} Books. They are:
       <input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="filter books..." aria-label="filter books" />    

          <ul data-drag="true"  data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" jqyoui-draggable="{index {{$index}},placeholder:true,animate:true}">
      <div class="repeater-container" vs-repeat>
        <!-- N.B: 
             1) class="animate-repeat" not included with fc-event
                means No : .animate-repeat.fc-event  included 
                in CSS File.
             2) orderBy book.contents['date'] is not working: 111 is                 the first one it should be the last one.
                book.contents['date'] uses $sce.trustAsHtml 
                see 173,174,175 lines in js file.
                also it uses ng-bind-html="book.contents['name']"
                see line 38 from html file

             3) when filtering by input text : 
                1 it works
                1Alain it doesn't work No results found...
                2Name it doesn't work No results found...
        -->
        <li class="animate-repeat fc-event" ng-repeat="book in books| orderBy: book.contents['date'] | filter:q as results track by book.contents['name']"  
             id="{{book.id}}">

        <div class="circle">{{book.contents['date']}}</div>
        <div class="left content" ng-bind-html="book.contents['name']" id="book_{{book.id}}"></div>
            <div class="left rating">2/10</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="animate-repeat" ng-if="results.length === 0">
                <strong>No results found...</strong>
            </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
  </div>
<div id='calendar-container'>
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>    


ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul>li {
  display:block;
    padding-right: 0cm;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

h4 {
  color: gray;
  display: inline; 
  border-bottom: 3px solid darken($fendersblue, 10);
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  font-size:600;
}


#calendar{
 padding: 0 10px;
 width: 650px;
 float: right;
 margin: 0px 0px 10px 55px;
}

#external-events {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 0 0px;
  border: 0px solid #ccc;/* gray moyen*/
  background: #eee;/* #5D6D7E;(Blue mat) */ /* #eee color gray*/
  text-align: left;
}

.repeater-container {
    height: 500px;
     width: 460px;
        overflow: auto;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 100;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

}


#external-events .fc-event {
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
  background: #eee;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

.content span
{
  color: gray;
}
.fc-event span:first-child
{
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold italic;
}



.fc-event div
{
  padding:3px;
  margin-right:5px;
  height: 100%;
}

.content
{
  float:left;
  max-width:75%;
}

.clear
{
  clear:both;
}

.circle {
  float:left;
  width: 10%;
  height: 25%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 360px;


  /* Just making it pretty */
  @shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  @shadow-length: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 @shadow-length 0 0 @shadow;
          box-shadow: 0 @shadow-length 0 0 @shadow;
  text-shadow: 0 @shadow-length 0 @shadow;
  background: #FFFFFF;/*color white*/
  color: #f05907;/* color red*/
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial Black, sans;
  font-size: 10;
  text-align: center;
}

.rating
{
  float:right;
  background: #FFFFFF;/*color white*/
  color: #f05907;/* color red*/
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial Black, sans;
  font-size: 10;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 360px;
}

.animate-repeat {
  line-height:30px;
  list-style:none;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.animate-repeat.ng-move,
.animate-repeat.ng-enter,
.animate-repeat.ng-leave {
  transition:all linear 0.5s;
}

.animate-repeat.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
.animate-repeat.ng-move,
.animate-repeat.ng-enter {
  opacity:0;
  max-height:0;
}

.animate-repeat.ng-leave,
.animate-repeat.ng-move.ng-move-active,
.animate-repeat.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
  max-height:30px;
}
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller("MainCtrl", ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce){

  $scope.books = [
                {
                    id: 'id1',
                    contents: {
                        name: '<span>1Alain du sceau france</span><br><span> Canada Madagascar philipine</span>',
                        price: 'price1',
                        date: '111'
                    }
                },
                {
                    id: 'id2',
                    contents: {
                        name: '<span>2Name zu Long zu Schreiben Bis Here ist Ein Beispiel</span><br><span>Maneschester Canada Madagascar philipine</span>',
                        price: 'price2',
                        date: '2'
                    }
                },
                {
                    id: 'id3',
                    contents: {
                        name: '<span>3name Aleatoire Schwer und zu Leicht Zu Schreiben</span><br><span>Mexico Canada USA France Uk Deutschland Schweiz Madagascar philipine</span>',
                        price: 'price3',
                        date: '3'
                    }
                },
                {
                    id: '4',
                    contents: {
                        name: '<span>4name Aleatoire Schwer und zu Leicht Zu Schreiben</span><br><span>Mexico Canada USA France Uk Deutschland Schweiz Madagascar philipine</span>',
                        price: 'price4',
                        date: '4'
                    }
            },
            {
                    id: 'id5',
                    contents: {
                        name: '<span>5name Aleatoire Schwer und zu Leicht Zu Schreiben</span><br><span>Mexico Canada USA France Uk Deutschland Schweiz Madagascar philipine</span>',
                        price: 'price5',
                        date: '5'
                    }
            },
            {
                    id: 'id6',
                    contents: {
                        name: '<span>6name Aleatoire Schwer und zu Leicht Zu Schreiben</span><br><span>Mexico Canada USA France Uk Deutschland Schweiz Madagascar philipine</span>',
                        price: 'price6',
                        date: '6'
                    }
            },
            {
                    id: 'id7',
                    contents: {
                        name: '<span>7name Aleatoire Schwer und zu Leicht Zu Schreiben</span><br><span>Mexico Canada USA France Uk Deutschland Schweiz Madagascar philipine</span>',
                        price: 'price7',
                        date: '7'
                    }
            },
            {
                    id: 'id8',
                    contents: {
                        name: '<span>8name Aleatoire Schwer und zu Leicht Zu Schreiben</span><br><span>Mexico Canada USA France Uk Deutschland Schweiz Madagascar philipine</span>',
                        price: 'price8',
                        date: '8'
                    }
            },
            {
                    id: 'id9',
                    contents: {
                        name: '<span>9name Aleatoire Schwer und zu Leicht Zu Schreiben</span><br><span>Mexico Canada USA France Uk Deutschland Schweiz Madagascar philipine</span>',
                        price: 'price9',
                        date: '9'
                    }
            },
               {
                    id: 'id10',
                    contents: {
                        name: '<span>10Alain du sceau france</span><br><span> Canada Madagascar philipine</span>',
                        price: 'price10',
                        date: '10'
                    }
                },
                {
                    id: 'id11',
                    contents: {
                        name: '<span>11Name zu Long zu Schreiben Bis Here ist Ein Beispiel</span><br><span>Maneschester Canada Madagascar philipine</span>',
                        price: 'price11',
                        date: '11'
                    }
                },
                {
                    id: 'id12',
                    contents: {
                        name: '<span>12name Aleatoire Schwer und zu Leicht Zu Schreiben</span><br><span>Mexico Canada USA France Uk Deutschland Schweiz Madagascar philipine</span>',
                        price: 'price12',
                        date: '12'
                    }
                },
                {
                    id: 'id13',
                    contents: {
                        name: '<span>13name Aleatoire Schwer und zu Leicht Zu Schreiben</span><br><span>Mexico Canada USA France Uk Deutschland Schweiz Madagascar philipine</span>',
                        price: 'price13',
                        date: '13'
                    }
            },
            {
                    id: 'id14',
                    contents: {
                        name: '<span>14name Aleatoire Schwer und zu Leicht Zu Schreiben</span><br><span>Mexico Canada USA France Uk Deutschland Schweiz Madagascar philipine</span>',
                        price: 'price14',
                        date: '14'
                    }
            },
            {
                    id: 'id15',
                    contents: {
                        name: '<span>15name Aleatoire Schwer und zu Leicht Zu Schreiben</span><br><span>Mexico Canada USA France Uk Deutschland Schweiz Madagascar philipine</span>',
                        price: 'price15',
                        date: '15'
                    }
            },
            {
                    id: 'id16',
                    contents: {
                        name: '<span>16name Aleatoire Schwer und zu Leicht Zu Schreiben</span><br><span>Mexico Canada USA France Uk Deutschland Schweiz Madagascar philipine</span>',
                        price: 'price16',
                        date: '16'
                    }
            },
            {
                    id: 'id17',
                    contents: {
                        name: '<span>17name Aleatoire Schwer und zu Leicht Zu Schreiben</span><br><span>Mexico Canada USA France Uk Deutschland Schweiz Madagascar philipine</span>',
                        price: 'price17',
                        date: '17'
                    }
            },
            {
                    id: 'id18',
                    contents: {
                        name: '<span>18name Aleatoire Schwer und zu Leicht Zu Schreiben</span><br><span>Mexico Canada USA France Uk Deutschland Schweiz Madagascar philipine</span>',
                        price: 'price18',
                        date: '18'
                    }
            },
            {
                    id: 'id19',
                    contents: {
                        name: '<span>19name Aleatoire Schwer und zu Leicht Zu Schreiben</span><br><span>Mexico Canada USA France Uk Deutschland Schweiz Madagascar philipine</span>',
                        price: 'price19',
                        date: '19'
                    }
            },
            {
                    id: 'id20',
                    contents: {
                        name: '<span>20name Aleatoire Schwer und zu Leicht Zu Schreiben</span><br><span>Mexico Canada USA France Uk Deutschland Schweiz Madagascar philipine</span>',
                        price: 'price20',
                        date: '20'
                    }
            }
            ];





  $scope.books.forEach(function(book) {
    book.contents.name =  $sce.trustAsHtml(book.contents.name);
  })

  $scope.h = function(html) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
  };


 $(document).ready( function(){     
                    //Initialise external events
                    initialise_external_event('.fc-event');
                    initialise_calendar();

    });





  // initialize the external events
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------
function initialise_external_event(selector){

  $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

  var reccupuredIndex=$(this).closest('li.fc-event').attr('id');
  var textContenu=$("#"+ "book_" +reccupuredIndex).html();
  /*
  $("div.left.content").each(function( index, element ) {
          // element == this
          // $( element ).css( "backgroundColor", "yellow" );
         var reccupuredIndexToSee=$(this).closest('li.fc-event').attr('id');
         var textContenuToSee=$("#"+"book_"+reccupuredIndexToSee).text();

         var myIndex="book_" +reccupuredIndexToSee;
         if ( $(this).is( "#"+myIndex) )  {

           alert($(this).text());

          }
  });
  */

    var myTitle=$.trim($(this).text());
    //$("span").text( "length:" +$("p.intro").get(0));

    // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
    $(this).data('event', {
      title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
      stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
    });

    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
    $(this).draggable({
      zIndex: 999,
      revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
      revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
    });

  });

}
  function initialise_calendar(){
  // initialize the calendar
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
    drop: function() {
      // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
      if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
        // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
        $(this).remove();
      }
    },
    eventDragStop: function(event, jsEvent, ui, view ) {

                      if(isEventOverDiv(jsEvent.clientX, jsEvent.clientY)) {


                          //////////
                          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
                 var el = $( "<div class='fc-event'>" ).appendTo('#external-        events').text(event.id);

    }
            }            
  });
var isEventOverDiv = function(x, y) {

                    var external_events = $( '#external-events' );
                    var offset = external_events.offset();
                    offset.right = external_events.width() + offset.left;
                    offset.bottom = external_events.height() + offset.top;

                    // Compare
                    if (x >= offset.left
                        && y >= offset.top
                        && x <= offset.right
                        && y <= offset .bottom) { return true; }
                    return false;

                }
 }

}]);
})(window.angular);
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller you iterate through each book and replace the value of the name field with the result of `$sce.trustAsHtml(book.content.name)` which is not the same as filtering over the strings.

I would probably err on the side of doing any html markup in the DOM and not using `$sce.trustAsHtml` but that's your choice.

You can bind the `$sce.trustAsHtml` to the scope in your controller like this 
`$scope.trustAsHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml` and then modify your DOM like I have below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.7"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-vs-repeat/blob/master/dist/angular-vs-repeat.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div id='external-events'>
  <h4 >Draggable books</h4>
  <br><br>I have {{books.length}} Books. They are:
       <input type="search" ng-model="searchText" placeholder="filter books..." aria-label="filter books" />    

          <ul data-drag="true"  data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" jqyoui-draggable="{index {{$index}},placeholder:true,animate:true}">
      <div class="repeater-container" vs-repeat>
        <!-- N.B: 
             1) class="animate-repeat" not included with fc-event
                means No : .animate-repeat.fc-event  included 
                in CSS File.
             2) orderBy book.contents['date'] is not working: 111 is                 the first one it should be the last one.
                book.contents['date'] uses $sce.trustAsHtml 
                see 173,174,175 lines in js file.
                also it uses ng-bind-html="book.contents['name']"
                see line 38 from html file

             3) when filtering by input text : 
                1 it works
                1Alain it doesn't work No results found...
                2Name it doesn't work No results found...
        -->
        <li class="animate-repeat fc-event" ng-repeat="book in books | orderBy: book.contents.date| filter:searchText as results track by book.contents.name"  
             id="{{book.id}}">

        <div class="circle">{{book.contents['date']}}</div>
        <div class="left content" ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(book.contents['name'])" id="book_{{book.id}}"></div>
            <div class="left rating">2/10</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="animate-repeat" ng-if="results.length === 0">
                <strong>No results found...</strong>
            </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
  </div>
<div id='calendar-container'>
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```